# After backing up PostgreSQL, the restoration process does not complete

Tags: postgresql

version 15
table is 4gb
17 column, 2 foreignkey in 17 column

pg_dump -U -d -t -a -Fc sss.dump

and i restore another database(version15)

pg restore -U -d sss.dump

"At first, the CPU usage is extremely high, but over time, it decreases to 1%, and the increase in table size becomes significantly smaller. However, even after several days, it does not complete."

i changed file format(dump, sql), compression Z (0,9), but it's same

Comment: You are not even showing the actual commands. Is the database into which you restore empty?

Comment: Please copy and paste the commands carefully and exactly, and format them as code.

Comment: 1) Did you move over the data the foreign keys point to? 2) What does the Postgres log show?